# Telerik Controls breaking MS-Build

Tags: .net, wpf, tfs, msbuild, telerik

Here is my XAML

```
   <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"     
    xmlns:sampleData="clr-namespace:AutoDeployStudio"
    xmlns:telerikControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:Chromes="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chromes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls" Foreground="BlueViolet"
    x:Class="AutoDeployStudio.MainWindow"           
    Title="MainWindow" Height="671.296" Width="1200.791">
        <Grid Background="OldLace"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1191" Height="639" VerticalAlignment="Top">      
           <telerik:RadTabControl Margin="313,233,10.4,10" telerikControls:StyleManager.Theme="Vista">
           <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Header1">        
            </telerik:RadTabItem>                         
          </telerik:RadTabControl>
        </Grid> 
   </Window>
```

Everytime i check in my this code in TFS i get a build failure with a error message saying "d:\B\66\5918\Sources\src\AutoDeployStudio\MainWindow.xaml (46): The tag 'RadTabControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation'. Line 46 Position 10."
I pretty much felt it was something to do with referencing the telerik assemblies. Thats why i relocated the dlls to a new folder within the solution and referenced them from that folder. Still it didn't work. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Did you *really* check that all necessary Telerik libraries are added to source control and available in that special folder? Did you *really* check that non of your project references any Telerik-libraries from other paths anymore?

Comment: Along the lines of spontifixus.  Are you referencing the telerik controls from the GAC ( on the dev box, and thus what exists in source-control ) or using "local references".  Most likely, its a GAC issue, or you don't atually have the files being retrieved in some manner (via source control, or the more "modern" way of using NuGet or Apache Ivy).

Comment: Hi eventhough all the telerik dlls were in that folder and paths specified to that folder. The program for some weird reason was looking outside that folder. So yes fixing the path in the project file itself solved the problem. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the structure needed in the proj file. The folder name being "dependencies".

```
<Reference Include="telerik.windows.controls, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\telerik.windows.controls.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="telerik.windows.controls.datavisualization, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\telerik.windows.controls.datavisualization.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="telerik.windows.controls.gridview, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\telerik.windows.controls.gridview.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="telerik.windows.controls.navigation, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\telerik.windows.controls.navigation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Data, Version=2013.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>dependencies\Telerik.Windows.Data.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```